# Half distance between two points in space

Tags: coordinate-systems

Given two points $A=(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $B=(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ on the tridimensional space how can I get the coordinates of the point located exactly on the half of the distance between the two points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That point is the midpoint of $AB$ and is given by $(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2},\frac{z_1+z_2}{2})$.

Comment: Thank you! I needed exactly this answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

The middle point of a segment $AB$ is determined by $\frac{OA+OB}{2}$, where $OA$ and $OB$ are the vectors determining the points $A,B$ and $O$ is the origin.